# A dream in which I remember "real" events

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I wonder if there is a word to describe a dream in which my conscience bridges reality and I remember real events in my dream world.  I recently had a dream like this. It was not a *lucid* dream, because I didn't realize I was dreaming until I woke up afterwards. In the dream I remembered events from a previous dream a week ago but also remembered real events from a day or two before and was somewhat confused by the inconsistency of the facts encountered. So my question is: **is there a name for such a dream?** Either a single word or a short phrase?

Answer (score 1):

[Vivid dream](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vivid?showCookiePolicy=true) could be used (Collins).

> conveying to the mind striking **realism,** freshness, or **trueness
> to life**; graphic
>
> (of a recollection, memory, etc) remaining distinct in the mind (of
>
> the imagination, etc) **prolific in the formation of lifelike images**